# Equivalent of MATLAB's colon operator in C/C++ with fftw

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to rewrite some of my MATLAB functions in C/C++ and wanted to know if there's an equivalent C/C++ operator to MATLAB's colon operator `:`
For example I have a MATLAB code as the following:

```
N = [Nx Ny];
M = 3 * N / 2;
    
% Make a new set of 2D matrices of only zeros. 
fk_pad = zeros(M(1), M(2));
    
% Get indices of the parts of the matrix we want to populate (zero padding)
    for i = 1:2
        ind_pad{i} = [1:N(i)/2 M(i)-N(i)/2+1:M(i)];
    end
    
% Populate zero matrices with our input of fk
    fk_pad(ind_pad{1},ind_pad{2}) = fk;
```

My code in C/C++ looks like:

```
static const int nx = 8, ny = 8;
static const int Mx = 3*nx/2, My= 3*ny/2;
double N[2] = {nx,ny};
// Make a new set of matrices of only zeros. 
    fftw_complex *fk_pad;
    fk_pad = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc((Mx*My)* sizeof(fftw_complex));
    memset(fk_pad, 42, (Mx*My) * sizeof(double)); //memset 42 initializes array to 1.42603e-105
```

But I am not sure how to implement the colon operator from the line: `ind_pad{i} = [1:N(i)/2 M(i)-N(i)/2+1:M(i)];` in my above code, especially with `fftw_malloc` which I am using in particular for FFTW3 library.

Thanks!

Comment: Would help others if you provide sample values for Nx, Mx, and fk.

Comment: Your question would be applicable to a wider audience if it described what "MATLAB's colon operator `:`" does. Providing example code is good, but it may require the reader to make assumptions about what it does, and assumptions lead to miscommunication. Textual descriptions are better (especially when combined with the example code).

Comment: A language I'm working on is called C/C++ — which is based on OCaml — supports the colon operator.  The C++ language does does not have anything like MATLAB's colon operator, you'll have to make your own.  The C language does not have anything like MATLAB's colon operator either.

Comment: If I recall correctly, that performs a _slice_ in MATLAB. It's not so much an _array_ operator as it is a vector generator. Using a vector as an index into a matrix then slices it. _Some_ of this functionality could be achieved with [std::slice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice). Setting up your own generic matrix class that provides this kind of flexibility is possible in C++, but not particularly straight-forward. There's certainly nothing built-in that I'm aware of.

Comment: `x = a:b:c` in Matlab produces a vector with elements `[a, a + b, a + 2 * b, .... , a + b*m]`    where `m` is the integral result of rounding `(c-a)/b` toward zero.   The wrinkle is that, if `a`, `b`, or `c` is not an integral value, the calculation of `m` may be affected by floating point (rounding) error.    In any event, a solution in C++ would be possible using `std::generate()` - the key will be setting up the generator (e.g. a lambda).

Comment: The OP's example also uses a 2-operand form of `:` (twice) - which has `b` in my previous comment equal to `1`.    `[a:b c:d]` is equivalent to appending two vectors (`a:1:b` and `c:1:d`)

Comment: Why don’t you just write a loop to generate the values to fill the array? Sure there are some tools in the C++ std lib that could be used to emulate the operation, but you don’t need to use those, it’s just as efficient (and probably easier) to write a plain old loop.